# how to loop through rows in an HTML table to find a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following sample html: https://jsfiddle.net/pgd8e46b/1/

What I'm trying to do is let the users click on a row from the "available_widgets" table and if it's not already in the "existing_widgets" table, add it and do other things.

I have the logic to grab the appropriate table and start the loop...

```
 var check_for_duplicates = function (row_id) {     
     var table = document.getElementById('existing_widgets');
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
     for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
         console.log(i);

     }
     console.log(rows);
     return true;
 }
```

but I don't know how to compare the ID field with the id that's passed in. 
I still have to write the logic that strips out the "row_" prefix from the id that's passed to the check_for_duplicates() method.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not necessarily a framework, but it sure is more efficient to play with JSON data than with DOM elements. But the idea here is to push every ID one by one in a predeclared empty array, but before doing that, check if the current ID is already in it (using `indexOf()`).

Comment: ID attribute shouldn't bring any data, you'd have better to use `data-*` attribute, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/pgd8e46b/5/

Comment: @blex could you give me small code snippet as a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify `check_for_duplicates` function if you use jQuery to find widget row by id:

```
$('#available_widgets').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    if (check_for_duplicates(this.id)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('otherwise, do other stuff');
    }
});

var check_for_duplicates = function (row_id) {
    return !!$('#existing_widgets').find('#' + row_id.replace('row_', '')).length;
}
```

Comment: This assumes jQuery, of which he is not using, in the function anyway

Comment: @lucky7id You are kidding right? OP is using jQuery.

Comment: @lucky7id The question tag and btw the jsFiddle let us believe OP is using jQuery

Comment: I edited for clarity, but yes, it is on the page in the plunkr, however, not in the submitted question. My mistake.

Comment: @lucky7id I was thinking the same before opening jsFiddle link... :)

Comment: this is great!  it works and it's a lot less code.  i still have to do reading to understand why it works.  but thanks again.

Comment: I can explain why it works. `row_id.replace('row_', '')` produces `245` from `row_245` by replacing `row_` substring. Then `$('#existing_widgets').find('#' + row_id.replace('row_', ''))` finds row with specified id like `#245`. If the row found then length of the returned collection will be greater than `0`. Finally, double negation `!!` converts length number to boolean value. So `0` => false, anything not equal to `0` => true.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `id` property in the returned elements.

`rows[i].id` should give you what you are looking for in your loop.

to strip off the prefix: `rows[i].id.replace('row_', '')` That will create a new string for you to compare against.

Comment: thanks for this.  it helped me understand what I was missing.  but i'm going to use the jquery solution because it's so much simpler than what i already have.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working function in JS. I would also suggest using some other prefix on the `existing_widgets` table, perhaps `existing_row_#`, and then you'd just need to modify the `replace()` component.

```
function check_for_duplicates(row_id) {
    var table = document.getElementById('existing_widgets');
    if (document.getElementById(row_id.replace('row_', ''))) {
        console.log(row_id + ' is a duplicate');
        return true;
    }  else {
        console.log(row_id + ' is not a duplicate');
        return false;
    }
 }
```